# What's the reason the static analysis wasn't made available to VS 2010 Pro?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, contracts

Is it so that the regular developers focus on writing their Contracts locally and then submit them to be analysed globally?

Or is there a way to get something comparable to this experience? Maybe as a separate download?

Also if a library have Contracts, then would the intellisense tooltips would include the Contracts no matter what version of VS is used?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question correctly, but the main reason why the bigger editions of VS have more features than the smaller ones is because otherwise they wouldn't be "bigger" editions.

This is a variant of third-degree price discrimination, and is really more on-topic on an economics Q&A site than StackOverflow.

Comment: Well I am not asking for why one has more features. That's obvious. But why this particular feature is left out, when the Contracts could still be utilized partially in any edition of VS. It's like being to code in C# in VS Pro, but not compile it. One is not really a feature without the other.

Comment: its not included because they want you to buy the version which has it included.

Comment: Ok thanks, because I am looking forward to using the Contracts framework, but only have pro, so wanted to make sure I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was forked off into a seperate project (on Devlabs) instead of a built-in / pre-packaged feature of Visual Studio.

Why did they make this change? That's a question for the developers I think. I guess they wanted to expose the concept separately, maybe allowing it to be used not just within studio.

Also, from my understanding of the package you'll download; you wont see any change in behavior with IntelliSense, It should integrate fully with visual studio's feature-set.

- [How-to: Install Code Contracts on Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/01/26/i-just-installed-visual-studio-2010-now-how-do-i-get-code-contracts-melitta-andersen.aspx)
- [Code Contracts Project Page (Devlabs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)